# How to Hide/Show 'div' using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can I show the text box depending on the user's selection in a dropdown box?

```
<select name="sites" id="select5" required="yes">
  <?php
   for($i=0;$i<=128;$i++){
     echo "<option>".$i."</option>";
   }                               
  ?>
</select>

<div id="YES"> 
 Other: <input class="input-text" type="text" name="name"/>
</div>
```

If the user selects 1 - the text box will not show.
Then if the user selects more than 2 -> the `<div id="YES">` will show.

Here's my jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#YES').hide();
    $("#select5").change(function(){
            $('#YES').hide('slow');
            $("#" + this.value).show('slow');
    });
    });
</script>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what's the pattern of showing/hiding the textbox?

Comment: Wait. Your `<option>` does not have `value` attribute.

Answer (score 6):

You can call the hide/show based on the value of the select like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#YES').hide();
    $("#select5").change(function () {
        $('#YES')[this.value > 1 ? 'show' : 'hide']('slow');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c4vq0tgk/)

Comment: Hi Arun P Johny, thanks a lot for your help. I owe you a cup of coffee. God Bless you.

Comment: Please explain this line some more details
`$('#YES')[this.value > 1 ? 'show' : 'hide']('slow');`

Comment: @TamilSelvan the requirement is we need to call the hide/show method based on the condition that if value > 1 the show else hide... So assuming you know the ternary operator... we are using the bracket notation to refer the hide/show method of the jQuery wrapper object based on the result of the ternary operation `this.value > 1`... so it is is true then we have `$('#YES')['show'](slow)` which is the same as `$('#YES').show(`slow`)`

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
$('#select5').on('change', function (e) {
var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
var valueSelected = this.value;
if(valueSelected == 1){
$('#YES').show();
}
else{ $('#YES').hide();}
});
```